# Change document type with PHP using URL file extension

Tags: php, html, header, content-type, file-extension

I am trying to change the document type using PHP by getting string from URL. This because i made a one page php website. All the contents will load up in one single `index.php` whether it is `HTML file`, `CSS file`, `Images (png, jpg, jpeg, etc)`, `XML`, etc

I noticed my files are loading fine in PHP but document type showing `HTML` by default for all type of content. I noticed this in `developer tool -> network tab`

**To achieve this, i am trying :**

```
$paraurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$file_extension = pathinfo(strtok($paraurl, '?'), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$exclude_url_extension = ["php", "html", "asp"];
$image_extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "tiff", "svg", "webp"];
$application_extensions = ["pdf", "json", "xml", "js"];
$text_extensions = ["html", "txt", "css"];

//if (!in_array($file_extension, $exclude_url_extension) && strrchr($paraurl, '.' . $file_extension) !== false) {
if (!in_array($file_extension, $exclude_url_extension) && strpos($paraurl, '.' . $file_extension) !== false) {
  header('Content-Disposition: inline');

  if (in_array($file_extension, $application_extensions)) {
    header('Content-type: application/' . $file_extension . '; charset=utf-8');
  } elseif (in_array($file_extension, $image_extensions)) {
    header('Content-type: image/' . $file_extension);
  } elseif (in_array($file_extension, $text_extensions)) {
    header('Content-type: text/' . $file_extension . '; charset=utf-8');
  }
}
```

**Issues i am facing :**

1. several files like .png, .jpg, .xsl, etc getting download automatically when it access through direct url (`https://example.com/example.png`) but it working fine when it embedded `<img src="https://example.com.png" />`
2. `sitemap.xml` is always getting broken but all rest is working fine. even i tried adding `charset=utf-8` in header but still `sitemap.xml` load broken
3. What should i use for XML (`text/xml` or `application/xml`) and javascript (`text/javascript` or `application/javascript` or `application/x-javascript`)
4. What should i use in `if` statement? `strrchr` or `strpos`

Comment: A `header('Content-Disposition: inline');` might force inline behavior? This should be the default behavior. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: @KIKOSoftware is this correct `header('Content-Disposition: inline; Content-type: application/' . $extension);`

Comment: I'm not sure you can send multiple headers in one `header()` call. Perhaps this is possible, but I cannot find any corroboration of this. And even if this arrives in the browser, does it have any effect? Finally, this is probably not how the `header()` call is supposed to be used, and if it works now it might not in the future. All this is speculation, of course.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i have updated my code and question. can you please check if it correct?

Comment: You've changed the code in your question, but not the issues you're facing. Does this mean that none of the changes you made had any impact on these issues?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `image` file direct access issue is fixed. `XML Sitemap` is also fixed. But 3rd one javascript is not fixed. even adding `Content-Disposition: inline` is automatically downloading

Comment: @KIKOSoftware also confused - What should i use in `if` statement? `strrchr` or `strpos`

Comment: See [a list of common mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types), it should be `application/xml` and `text/javascript`. Remember that your browser ultimately determines what happens with certain file types and the browser might, in turn, defer this to the OS. In case you only want to check if a substring is present both `strrchr()` and `strpos()` will work. Finally, your edits are confusing for people who read your question for the first time. They probably won't read all the comments as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

```
$paraurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$file_extension = pathinfo(strtok($paraurl, '?'), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$exclude_url_extension = ["php", "html", "htm", "asp", "aspx"];
$image_extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "tiff", "webp", "avif"];
$application_extensions = ["pdf", "json", "xml", "zip"]; 
$text_extensions = ["html", "txt", "css", "csv"];
$audio_extensions = ["mpeg", "wav", "m4a", "mp3", "aac", "m4b"];
$video_extensions = ["mp4", "ogg", "webm", "quicktime", "x-msvideo", "x-flv", "mpeg", "3gpp", "x-ms-wmv", "x-matroska"];


if (!in_array($file_extension, $exclude_url_extension) && strpos($paraurl, '.' . $file_extension) !== false) {
    header('Content-Disposition: inline');
    
    if (in_array($file_extension, $application_extensions)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/' . $file_extension . '; charset=utf-8');
    } else if (in_array($file_extension, $image_extensions)) {
        header('Content-Type: image/' . $file_extension);
    } else if (in_array($file_extension, $text_extensions)) {
        header('Content-Type: text/' . $file_extension . '; charset=utf-8');
    } else if ($file_extension === "js") {
        header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    } else if (in_array($file_extension, $video_extensions)) {
        header('Content-Type: video/' . $file_extension);
    } else if (in_array($file_extension, $audio_extensions)) {
        header('Content-Type: audio/' . $file_extension);
    } else if ($file_extension === "weba") {
        header('Content-Type: audio/webm');
    } else if ($file_extension === "oga") {
        header('Content-Type: audio/ogg');
    } else if ($file_extension === "ogv") {
        header('Content-Type: video/ogg');
    } else if ($file_extension === "ogx") {
        header('Content-Type: application/ogg');
    } else if ($file_extension === "svg") {
        header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
    } else if ($file_extension === "xhtml") {
        header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8');
    } else if ($file_extension === "xls") {
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    } else if ($file_extension === "xlsx") {
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    } else if ($file_extension === "jpg") {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    } else if ($file_extension === "doc") {
        header('Content-Type: application/msword');
    } else if ($file_extension === "docx") {
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    } else if ($file_extension === "ppt") {
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');
    } else if ($file_extension === "pptx") {
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation');
    } else if ($file_extension === "vsd") {
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.visio');
    } else if ($file_extension === "ico") {
        header('Content-Type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon');
    } else if ($file_extension === "ics") {
        header('Content-Type: text/calendar');
    } else if ($file_extension === "rar") {
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.rar');
    } else if ($file_extension === "tar") {
        header('Content-Type: application/x-tar');
    } else if ($file_extension === "7z") {
        header('Content-Type: application/x-7z-compressed');
    } else if ($file_extension === "gz") {
        header('Content-Type: application/gzip');
    }

}
```